# Error al diseñar un programa para media de notas de alumnos y media sueldo profesores con diccionarios

Tags: c#, diccionarios

Necesito diseñar un programa que recoja la información de 10 personas. Estas personas pueden ser alumnos o profesores y, de entrada no sabré cuántos habrá de cada. Por cada alumno debo recopilar su nombre y su nota en una asignatura, mientras que por cada profesor deberás recoger el nombre y el sueldo. Finalmente, el programa debe mostrar por pantalla la media de las notas de todos los alumnos leídos y la suma de los sueldos de todos los profesores.

El error es:

```
(1)Unhandled Exception:
    System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
      at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x0005e] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00014] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00007] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at Program.Main () [0x00063] in <92848947a0a743adb15d405b15e83f09>:0 
    [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
      at System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) [0x0005e] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) [0x00014] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00007] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
      at Program.Main () [0x00063] in <92848947a0a743adb15d405b15e83f09>:0
    Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) 
    Insert teacher name: 
    Insert teacher salary:
```

Y un funcionamiento correcto del programa sería este:

```
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) t
Insert teacher name: T1
Insert teacher salary: 1000.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) t
Insert teacher name: T2
Insert teacher salary: 1000.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) t
Insert teacher name: T3
Insert teacher salary: 1000.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) t
Insert teacher name: T4
Insert teacher salary: 1000.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) t
Insert teacher name: T5
Insert teacher salary: 1000.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) s
Insert student name: S1
Insert student note: 10.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) s
Insert student name: S2
Insert student note: 5.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) s
Insert student name: S3
Insert student note: 7.5
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) s
Insert student name: S4
Insert student note: 1.00
Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) s
Insert student name: S5
Insert student note: 8.00
The total sum of salaries of the 5 teachers is 5000.
The averge note of the 5 students is 6.3.
Press any key.
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string resposta;
        int numprof = 0, numal = 0, mitjasou = 0, mitjanotes = 0;
        string nom;
        IDictionary<string, int> professors = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        IDictionary<string, int> alumnes = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) ");
            resposta = Console.ReadLine();
            if (resposta == "t")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert teacher name: ");
                nom = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert teacher salary: ");
                professors.Add(nom, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                numprof += 1;
            }
            else if (resposta == "s")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert student name: ");
                nom = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert student note: ");
                alumnes.Add(nom, int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                numal += 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> user in professors)
        {
            mitjasou += user.Value;
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> user in alumnes)
        {
            mitjanotes += user.Value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The averge note of the {0} students is {1}. ", alumnes.Count, mitjanotes/alumnes.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("The total sum of salaries of the {0} teachers is {1}. ", alumnes.Count, mitjasou/professors.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se debe a que `int.Parse()` está recibiendo una cadena con formato decimal.

La solución es modificar el programa para usar double en lugar de int.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string resposta;
        double numprof = 0, numal = 0, mitjasou = 0, mitjanotes = 0;
        string nom;
        var professors = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        var alumnes = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Are you going to insert a teacher or a student? (t/s) ");
            resposta = Console.ReadLine();
            if (resposta == "t")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert teacher name: ");
                nom = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert teacher salary: ");
                professors.Add(nom, double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                numprof += 1;
            }
            else if (resposta == "s")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Insert student name: ");
                nom = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert student note: ");
                alumnes.Add(nom, double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                numal += 1;
            }
        }
        foreach (var user in professors)
        {
            mitjasou += user.Value;
        }
        foreach (var user in alumnes)
        {
            mitjanotes += user.Value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The averge note of the {0} students is {1}. ", alumnes.Count, mitjanotes/alumnes.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("The total sum of salaries of the {0} teachers is {1}. ", alumnes.Count, mitjasou/professors.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```